# Creating a child class where the child can call it's function in a parent class in React Native

Tags: react-native, wrapper

Say that I have the following code as my child class:

```
export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style = {styles.horizontalView}>
                {this.props.children}
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText = {() => { 
                        someFunction()
                        //call someFunction() in a parent class
                    }} 
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, in my parent class I want to be able to do something like:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    //someFunction is called by the child but is defined here by the parent.
    someFunction() {

    }

    render() {

    }
}
```

Let me know if you have a solution to this problem. Thank you again.

Comment: The code does *not* show a "child class". If there *was* a parent-child *class/type* relationship established, the method would be available to the parent class "and all derived/child classes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    //someFunction is called by the child but is defined here by the parent.
    someFunction() {

    }

    render() {
       <ChildComponent parentFunction={this.someFunction}/>
    }
}
```

Then in childComponent

```
export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style = {styles.horizontalView}>
                {this.props.children}
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText = {() => { 
                        //call someFunction() in a parent class
                        this.props.parentFunction();
                    }} 
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```